# Retirar string campo MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy haciendo un query en MySQL y debo separar de un campo el prefijo para dejar únicamente el numero posterior, que función dentro del query puedo utilizar?

este es el query

```
SELECT lugar, descripcion, boleto_ganador, colab_ganador 
FROM sorteoupaep_test.premio 
where clave_sorteo="sorteo 2019" 
and tipo="sortcolab" 
order by lugar;
```

y de la columna `boleto_ganador` que se compone de la siguiente forma `"BC2019-234"` quiero eliminar el texto `"BC2019-"` y dejar únicamente el número posterior al guión.

Comment: Suigiero que incluyas no solo un dato de muestra, sino varias filas, para hacerse una mejor idea de la solución, por ejemplo, si la longitud de la cadena a quitar es siempre la misma, si hay varios caracteres separadores, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si siempre es el mismo patrón `BC2019-234` entonces el delimitador lo tomaremos como un `-`

Podemos buscarlo de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT lugar, descripcion, colab_ganador,
SUBSTRING(boleto_ganador, (POSITION("-" IN boleto_ganador ) + 1)) AS 'boleto_ganador'
FROM sorteoupaep_test.premio 
where clave_sorteo="sorteo 2019" 
and tipo="sortcolab" 
order by lugar;
```

Comment: perfecto, con esto quedo excelente, muchas gracias.